# LaTeX chemfig library is not getting installed

Tags: python

I TRIED TO INSTALL Manim and Chanim , there installing \tlmgr chemfig in Google Colab but it's having a problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfvSF.jpg)

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

download this lib from pip
first:
**download python and select pip**   [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU91P.jpg)
and continue

Comment: Actually I want to download it in google Colab notebook

Comment: Why does a LaTeX package require Python?